# In php how do I execute code stored in a mysql field as php code?

Tags: php

I plan to store some code, possibly mixed with simple html in a database field:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select id,code, script from articles where id=117;
+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
| id  | code                                    | script         |
+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
| 117 | <?php echo "Good Golly Miss Molly<br />"; ?> | code/hello.php |
+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looking at some other posts eval() is typically the way to go, but eval does not seem to work when you include php tags or possibly raw html.

```
$query = "
select
code,
script
from articles
where articles.id = 117
";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$code = $row["code"];
$script = $row["script"];

eval($code);
eval("$code");
```

Both work with raw code (no ) tags, but fail with the tags and plain html. Another way to get the job done is to place the script or html in a file and use include().

Is there a way to use eval() to execute mixed code with tags and raw html?

-------------------- Note added: Friday, Oct 18, 2019 --------------

Here's a hacky way to solve the problem:

```
$rand = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 24);
$fpi = fopen("$some_folder/$rand.php", "w");
fwrite($fpi, "$code");
fclose($fpi);

include ("$some_folder/$rand.php");
unlink ("$some_folder/$rand.php");
```

No comment regarding security, but this does get you from point A to point B

Comment: See [`eval(str)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) - **"The code [supplied to eval] must not be wrapped in opening and closing [tags]"** - so strip the tags / don't provide [or store] the tags originally / or use a different method. (This setup is a bit questionable overall, as it is leads to SECOND ORDER INJECTION VULNERABILITIES ..)

Comment: It may be worthwhile considering a restricted execution template environment. If wishing to 'run PHP as PHP', most variations will be wrappers around the temporary file which is included - slightly 'safer' variations might run in a different execution context with limited access (eg. a proxy-execution service). As far as the "usage" goes, it could be `evalAsMixedPhpContent($mixedCodeFromDb);` - see "use a different method".

Comment: Can you explain why you would do that thing?

Comment: At this time it's just an idea. Access would be extremely limited so I really would not be concerned with injection. I have a simple CMS where I store articles and meta information in a table. At this point to do anything custom (basic script etc) I have to add the coding in the article files - and this works (am trying to move away from this). I like the idea of being able to store the code in an admin form and maintain less files in the filesystem.

Comment: I'm just gonna drop this here in advance. https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server